# total2's value is too strange！I can't get the right values

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h> 

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char p[80],m[80];
    int length1,length2,b,i,j,total,total2;

    puts("input base Dividend Divisor");
    scanf("%d %s %s",&b,&p,&m);

    length1 = strlen(p);
    length2 = strlen(m);

    for (i=0;i<=length1;i++) {
        total+=(p[i]-'0')*pow(b,length1-1);
        length1--;
    }
```

I think that two for loops is mostly the same.
Why I can't get what I want.

```
    for (j=0;j<=length2;j++) {
        total2+=(m[j]-'0')*pow(b,length2-1);
        length2--;
    }

    printf("%d %d",total,total2);

    return 0; 
}
```

I can't get the right values.

Comment: both `total` and `total2` are uninitialised values..  it would help if you also said what you want

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You will greatly increase your chances of getting your problem fixed if you include the following in your question: what you are trying to do, your input, your expected output, your actual output and any error messages you might receive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String input with `scanf` do not require `&`.
Therefore, instead of this:

```
scanf("%d %s %s",&b,&p,&m);
```

try this:

```
scanf("%d %s %s",&b,p,m);
```

Also,

```
total+=(p[i]-'0')*pow(b,length1-1);
```

the initial value of `total` may be some garbage value, you need to initialise it:

```
total=0; total2=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

For a start, you are not initialising your total variables to zero, so they'll both start with an arbitrary value.

A simple

```
total = total2 = 0;
```

before the loops start will fix that.

You may also want to look in to the `strtol` family of functions since it already provides a way to convert strings into integers.